# Scrolled to the bottom of a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to find out when the user has scrolled to the bottom of a UITableView?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget that TableView is UIScrollView  subclass :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UITableview delegate has a method called

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If the method is called and the indexPath variable is equal to the indexPath of the last row in your dataset then the view is about to display the last row of the table.